# Filtering in Nuxt 3 with Asynchronous Data

Tags: vuejs3, filtering, vue-composition-api, sanity, nuxt3

I'm rendering a list of projects in Nuxt 3, where each project has a title, description, and genre. I want users to be able to filter projects by genre through a text input, performing the filtering on the front-end only.

I would typically use a computed property for this, but I'm unsure how to apply it when the data is resolved asynchronously:

`const { data } = await useSanityQuery( singleProjectQuery, params, mainStore.sanityClient )`

After the promise resolves, my projects are available on `data.projects`.

`useSanityQuery` is a data fetching composable that wraps `useAsyncData` from Nuxt 3, and I'm using the Composition API.

How can I filter projects by genre in this case? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a computed property and filter `data.projects` in it. and in your list use this computed property. and because `data.projects` is nullable, just check for it before filtering.

```js
const searchText = ref("")

const filteredProjects = computed(() =>
    data && data.projects && data.projects.filter(
        (p) => p.genre.includes(searchText.value)
    ) || []
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So even though the data resolves async, a computed value still works? I just need to null check inside the computed function before doing any filtering?

Comment: yes. that's enough. because you're using await.